# PHP: __set function behaviour different each time

Tags: php

This manages to create a new property on the object.  But, can someone explain, with supporting links, why `setAttrib` behaves in two different ways?  Why doesn't it cause a... wait for it... stack overflow!!??

```
class Test
{
  public function setAttrib( $key, $value ) {
    echo "setAttrib\n";

    // first time: calls $this->__set($key, $value)
    // second time: just sets a public property (but, when exactly was it created?)
    $this->$key = $value;
  }

  public function __set( $key, $value ) {
    echo "__set\n";
    $this->setAttrib($key, $value);
  }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->setAttrib('hey', 'It works');
var_dump($test);
```

produces...

```
setAttrib
__set
setAttrib
object(Test)#1 (1) {
  ["hey"]=>
  string(8) "It works"
}
```

Edit: I'm not looking for an alternative.  *I'm looking for the reason why this works.*

Comment: Not sure if it'll change anything, but your __set method should be public (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php which states "All overloading methods must be defined as public." -- and the warning you get when running your code)

Comment: Yep, you're right there, and I changed it to public.  Same behaviour.

Comment: At least, that's one warning that is no more ^^ (I didn't think it would change anything else, which is why I only posted a comment ; but one warning gone is always a good thing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not the only one who seems to have notice that non-recursive behaviour : [this comment on the manual's page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#93939) states :

> 2 - PHP will not recursively call one
>   magic method from within itself (at
>   least for the same `$name`).

And, a bit later on the same page, there is [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#93939), which states :

> The recursion detection feature can
>   prove especially perilous when using
>   `__set`. When PHP comes across a
>   statement that would usually call
>   `__set` but would lead to recursion,
>   rather than firing off a warning or
>   simply not executing the statement it
>   will act as though there is no `__set`
>   method defined at all. 
> The default
>   behaviour in this instance is to
>   dynamically add the specified property
>   to the object thus breaking the
>   desired functionality of all further
>   calls to `__set` or `__get` for that
>   property.

And, on PHP's bugtracker, there is [#47215 : magic method __set() is bypassed on recursive call](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47215), which says :

> Magic method `__set()` is bypassed on
>   recursive call.  
> PHP automatically
>   creates a property on instance instead
>   of recursively calling `__set()` or
>   instead of throwing a recursivity
>   error

And it has been closed as :

> Thank you for taking the time to write
>   to us, but this is not a bug.

That bug-report, itself, points to [this blog-post](http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=458), which ends by this sentence *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

> After all I think it may not be a bug
>   but expected behaviour, **otherwise we
>   could not be able to define object
>   properties from within `__set()`
>   method**.

Comment: For me, PHP is calling __set() cursively and it's driving me nuts, I can't dynamically define properties and have magic __set in the same class. I am using PHP 5.3.2. Did they change this behavior, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2):

__set is only used when writing to inaccessible properties. That is, those who are not accessible (private or protected) or those that aren't set at all. Therefore, __set will only be called once.

Here's what happens:

- setAttrib: Attempt to write
- class: inaccessible property
- __set: Do whatever __set is told to do, which is call setAttrib again.
- setAttrib: Attempt to write
- class: inaccessible property, but __set can't recurse, and we're already in it, so do it as if __set didn't exist.

See user comments for http://php.net/__set for proof that __set can't recurse.

Comment: I'm wondering, when exactly is the 'hey' member created?  There's more than meets the eye here.

Comment: It is written on the last run of setAttrib.

Comment: it happening in your very first call to set attribute. `__set` will never catch it unless you do `$a = new MyClass(); $a->hey = 'my text';` from within a class that doesnt have access to `MyClass::$hey`.

Comment: Actually it does catch it, because the property isn't set. But __set isn't recursive, so it can only be called once per stack.

Answer (score 0):

`__set` and `__get` only catch the call for the property if the member is protected. meaning that within the object `$this->$key` sets the property `$key`. if called from out of scope then the `__set` logic is called. One of your calls happens in the object outside the object.